# "He likes swimming" or "He likes to swim"?

Tags: difference, infinitives, gerunds, licensing

One can say: *He likes swimming* or *He likes to swim*. What is the exact meaning of each of these? What is the difference?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The two are often interchangeable but not always.  While *he likes to swim* always means that he enjoys propelling himself through the water using his own body power, *he likes swimming* could also be used if he enjoys watching it as a spectator:

> "The Olympics are on- we could watch swimming or running.  Isn't Bill coming over?  He likes swimming, so we should watch that."

Comment: Smart distinction. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: That sentence isn't ambiguous, though. Rather, there are two sentences and they have distinct structures. In one sentence _swimming_ is the verb of an object gerund clause with _he_ understood as its subject, and in the other it's a noun like _golf_ or _football_. Naturally, the two sentences don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

The two are interchangeable.  "He likes swimming" means "He likes the act of going to swim."  They mean the same thing and you can say either.

Answer (score 4):

There is an interesting commentary on the similarities and differences between *like* + gerund and *like* + infinitive [here](http://valentinamorgana.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/teaching-younger-teenage-learners-to-express-likes-and-wants/).  I have not yet finished digesting it but there is definitely some food for thought there, for both EFL teachers and students on this issue.