# Why is "like to swim" possible, but "enjoying to swim" is not?

Tags: verb-forms

I read that *like swimming* and *like to swim* ["are often interchangeable"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/he-likes-swimming-or-he-likes-to-swim):

> [...] While **he likes to swim** always means that he enjoys propelling himself through the water using his own body power, **he likes swimming** could also be used if he enjoys watching it as a spectator.

However, while *liking* and *enjoying* don't seem to be very different (the former meaning "[find agreeable, enjoyable, or satisfactory](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/like--2)" and the latter meaning "[take delight or pleasure in (an activity or occasion)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enjoy?q=enjoy)"), *enjoy to swim* is ungrammatical.

Therefore, I would like to know what the difference is between *liking* and *enjoying* in reference to the fact that, while *like to swim* is possible, **enjoy to swim* is not.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no rhyme, reason, or rule to it. See also *[“I end up studying English” vs. “I end up to study English”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11293/i-end-up-studying-english-vs-i-end-up-to-study-english)* as well as *[When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive)* at EL&U and [Wiktionary's list of catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_catenative_verbs).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but the answer is that "while *like to swim* is possible, **enjoy to swim* is not".

I realise that this is just repeating the last part of your question, but there is no more helpful answer. I could restate it in technical language ("*like* subcategorises for a gerund or a to-infinitive, while *enjoy* subcategorises only for a gerund") but that wouldn't explain anything.