# "She enjoys being photographed"

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds, causatives

Passive simple gerund

1. She enjoys being photographed .
2. Her baby loves being
   held .
3. I hate being lied to.
4. She denied being invited.

http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-gerund

My questions:
Can or should the simple gerund passive refer to the same time as the verb in the main clause?

```
            OR
```

Can it also refer to an earlier event mentioned by the verb in the main clause?

```
            OR
```

Do I need to use *having* to refer to a time before the verb in main clause?

For example, ***She enjoys*** is written in the present tense, does the second clause,  ***being photographed***,  refer to the present or the past?

I want to how to use the 'passive simple' gerund to refer to the past, present, and future.

Comment: It is time-independent.  I hate being lied to = I hate being lied to in the past, in the present, and in the future.  If it's meant otherwise, it will be qualified - "I used to hate being lied to, but now I'm OK with it"

Comment: You know the answer is given right on the page you refer to, which includes the sentences **The simple gerund can refer to the same time as that of the verb in the main clause** and **The simple gerund can also refer to a time before that of the verb in the main clause** and gives examples of both uses.

Comment: @Alan Carmack But I'm talking about 'passive simple gerund' which is passive of simple gerund. I want to how to use 'passive simple' gerund to refer to past present and future.

Comment: If the example I used conveys exactly what you are asking- hooray!! ;) If, instead, I'm mistaken *sob* (sad face), you'll have to either fix or delete it. Hope the edit helped.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm sorry that  no one has posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to help.

In the first example, the sentence

> *She **enjoys being** photographed*

tells us that the person **enjoys *having*** her photo taken.

What does this sentence mean? It means whenever someone takes a picture of her, she is pleased, and does not feel embarrassed or bored by this simple activity. She **doesn't mind** ***posing*** in front of the camera. In fact, she **likes to have** her photo taken.

This exemplifies the use of the present simple tense, the present simple is used to convey something which is either a fact, or an action that is habitual. Instead, if she regularly uploaded images that she took of *herself*, we might say:

> She **enjoys taking** selfies

With verbs of preferences, e.g. *like*, *love*, *enjoy*, *don't mind*, etc. it is common to use the present simple tense. We do not *normally* say

> She **is enjoying** ***being*** photographed

While the construction is not forbidden, it is acceptable in speech and in most English dialects,  it seems to have a slightly different meaning from the original; here the subject is currently experiencing enjoyment while someone is taking two or more photos of her. The subject could be a child who is  happy and excited that she is photographed on her birthday.

If we wanted to refer to this ‘enjoyment’ in the **Past Simple** tense we would say

> She **enjoyed** having her photo taken (at the party).
>   She **enjoyed** being photographed

to express future meaning we might say

> She is **going to** enjoy having her photo taken
>   She is going to enjoy being photographed
>   She **will** enjoy having her photo taken
>   She will enjoy being photographed.

One last point, although it is grammatical to use either the infinitive or the gerund  after the verb *like*

> She **likes to be** photographed
>   She **likes being** photographed

The same is not true for the verb *enjoy*, it is best to avoid the infinitive after the verb *enjoy*.

> She **enjoys to be** photographed. NO

For more insight, read Colin Fine's answer in

[Why is "like to swim" possible, but "enjoying to swim" is not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/why-is-like-to-swim-possible-but-enjoying-to-swim-is-not)

and Stoney B's answer in: ["I end up studying English" vs. "I end up to study English"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11293/i-end-up-studying-english-vs-i-end-up-to-study-english) and in [Two consecutive gerunds? -ing -ing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44078/two-consecutive-gerunds-ing-ing)

Comment: I upvoted this answer!

Comment: @yubrajsharma well thanks. I'm sure someone will find a fault in it, somewhere. But I tried my best. I do hope this has helped you.